# Return the value of a nested dictionary or nested list with a Dynamic Index

Tags: python

I am making a function that would get data from API queries and I need to have a dynamic indexing regardless if it is a list of dictionaries, dictionaries inside of a dictionary and so on.

Is it possible to create a function that would return the value of a nested dictionary or nested list with a Dynamic Index? I have tried one but it uses exec() which I think is not a good idea.

For example I have multiple lists and dictionaries.

```
Set1={"A":{"a":1,"b":2}}
Set2=[1,2,3]
Set3=[{"C":3},{"D":2}]
```

And I would need to index all of the Sets that have a value of "2."

Would it be possible to create something like

```
Function["A"]["b"]
Function[1]
Function[1]["D"]
```

Since all of them would just return 2?

Comment: How does `Function` know which obj to evaluate?

Comment: That's my problem. My first solution was using a function which has two parameters, the object itself and a string that is basically the index.  
  
So it looked like  
`Function(Set1,"["A"]["B"]")`  
`Function(Set2,"[1]")`  
`Function(Set3,"[1]["D"]")`

Answer (score 2):

It is not strictly necessary to use the index/key access notation. You could write a function along the following lines:

```
def accessor(data, *bits):
    for bit in bits:
        try:
            data = data[bit]
        except (TypeError, KeyError, IndexError):
            raise 
            # or handle differently
    return data

>>> accessor(Set1, "A", "b")
2
>>> accessor(Set2, 1)
2
>>> accessor(Set3, 1, "D")
2
```

Note that if you receive the `bits` dynamically, e.g. as a `list`, you can unpack them like:

```
# e.g. bits = ["A", "b"]
accessor(Set1, *bits)
```

Comment: This is it! I didn't know you can also use "*" in parameters. I only know you can use it in zip. Thank you so much.

Comment: The unpacking operators `*` and `**`are a general feature and can be used in many contexts, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists. `zip(*...)` is just that case. It expects multiple arguments and `*` unpacks a list/iterable of such arguments.